# Combining Unique Pairs of Files with find

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, filenames

I have a series of actions I need to preform on pairs of files, on a fair number of files. For simplicity, I'll focus this down on just doing a simple cat on a pair, to discuss the pairing and how to write the most straight forward pairing part of shell script.

Say I have 4 files, A.txt, B.txt, C.txt, and D.txt, and I want to write a compact script that will basically do:

```
 cat A.txt B.txt > AB.txt
 cat A.txt C.txt > AC.txt
 cat A.txt D.txt > AD.txt
 cat B.txt C.txt > BC.txt
 cat B.txt D.txt > BD.txt
 cat C.txt D.txt > CD.txt
```

I want to have one output for each unique combination, and AD.txt and DA.txt are not "unique" by this criteria.

But I'd like to make it a bit easier than as a shell script, that I can do for different sets of files, and just run it in a directory, and have it find all matches recursively. I immediately seem to have went the wrong direction, and made a mess of things:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec [[SOME MAGIC CODE CREATING PAIRS OF FILE NAMES]] {} \; 
 \ cat "$MAGICPAIRfile1".txt "$MAGICPAIRfile2".txt >  
 \ "$MAGICPAIRfile1"-"$MAGICPAIRfile2".txt
```

was thinking of exec'ing a couple pieces in there, one that dumps file names to a text buffer (bad buffer type for file name character strings, so I didn't), and then pass that buffer to yet another exec {} \;.

But I thought someone else might have a good idea?

Comment: Re recursiveness: should `./A` be paired with `./dir/B`, or do you just need `./A`+`./B` (in each dir)?

Comment: also based on what conditions first file should be `A.txt` and second `B.txt` in `cat A.txt B.txt > AB.txt`, or being first and second files doesn't matter and any one of `XY.txt` or `YX.txt` is fine but not both for `X.txt` and `Y.txt` files? also what if you had 5files, I mean if last one file remain single?

Comment: My find criteria changes, so each value will have a full path as input value to the scripted loop, which won't always be 'cat'

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion.

```
#!/bin/bash
files="empty"
for i in A B C D ; do
    for j in B C D ; do
     fn="$i$j"
     nf="$( echo $fn | rev )"
     # if nn is 1 $nf wasn't found in $files
      nn=1
      for q in $files ; do
        if [[ "$q" == "$nf" ]] ; then
               nn=0
         fi
        done
        if  [[  $nn -eq 1 ]] && [[ "$fn" != "$nf" ]] 
        then
           echo "cat $i.txt $j.txt >$fn.txt"
        fi
        files="$fn $nf $files"
    done
done
```

Comment: This is getting there, it's the embedded loop solution I was thinking of, I might edit this? If I can make the A, B, C, D and input from find, I'm pretty sure it might do what I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the file arguments of your `find` command into an array. Also you can `sort` them before saving. Here, null separation has been used (`-d ''` for `mapfile` (==`readarray`), `-print0` for `find` and `-z` for `sort`) which requires GNU utilities.

And do a double loop for them, `i` is running the whole length and `j` from `i+1` to the end, and create the combinations. You can process into there each combination of the file arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -d '' arr < <(find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | sort -z)

for ((i=0; i<"${#arr[@]}"; i++)); do
    for ((j=i+1; j<"${#arr[@]}"; j++)); do
        printf "Processing files: %s %s\n" "${arr[i]}" "${arr[j]}"
    done
done
```

```
Processing files: ./A.txt ./B.txt
Processing files: ./A.txt ./C.txt
Processing files: ./A.txt ./D.txt
Processing files: ./B.txt ./C.txt
Processing files: ./B.txt ./D.txt
Processing files: ./C.txt ./D.txt
```

---

For your specific example, to `cat` the files and have the desired output filename (assuming they are all in the same directory level), you could use `find ... -printf '%f\0'`, to print only the filenames, and substring removal with parameter expansion, to create the commands. Slightly modified version, using newline separator for the filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t arr < <(find . -type f -name '*.txt' -printf "%f\n" | sort)

for ((i=0; i<"${#arr[@]}"; i++)); do
    for ((j=i+1; j<"${#arr[@]}"; j++)); do
        cat "${arr[i]}" "${arr[j]}" > "${arr[i]%.*}${arr[j]}"
    done
done
```

Comment: I think that might be the magic I need!
```
mapfile -d '' arr < <(find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | sort -z)
```
However, I'm getting:
```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: Is ddrescueview required for "mapfile?"

Comment: Ah, yea, silly me, tested by doing "sh bashscript.sh" and wonders why the "bash" parts weren't working! Sorry. Yes, it works just as you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `perl` and assuming your filenames are "well-behaved":

```
find ... |
perl -0777 -MMath::Combinatorics -anE \
  'BEGIN{$,=" "}; say sort(@$_) for (combine(2, @F))' |
sort
```

Output when `A\nB\nC\nD\n` is the input:

```
A B
A C
A D
B C
B D
C D
```

To recreate your example (GNU sed):

```
... |
sed -E 's/([^.]+).([^ ]+) ([^.]+).([^ ]+)/cat \1.\2 \3.\4 > \1\3.\2/'
```

```
cat A.txt B.txt > AB.txt
cat A.txt C.txt > AC.txt
cat A.txt D.txt > AD.txt
cat B.txt C.txt > BC.txt
cat B.txt D.txt > BD.txt
cat C.txt D.txt > CD.txt
```

Which can then be piped to a shell for execution or done with the `/e` flag in GNU sed.